# Magento2 | Set limit of sending emails every day

Tags: magento2, email, newsletter, newsletter-subscriber

I created in the Magento2 backend a newsletter campaign and it will be sent to 6000 subscribers. In my server there is a sending limit at 2000 emails per day.

Can I set the limit on Magento2 not to send more than 2000 emails per day?
I remember on Magento1 the section was, "Marketing > Newsletter > Configuration > Queue Configuration".

In Magento2 backend where can I find this setting?